# Subquery returns more than one row after creating view

Tags: mysql, view

```
CREATE VIEW `report_central_class` AS
SELECT a.*,b.course_title,b.outline_id,c.catid,d.main_title,
      (select comp_name 
       from lang_company_details 
       where comp_id = (select comp_id 
                        from lang_company_details_courses 
                        where course_id=a.course_id)
       ) as company, 
       (select concat(fname,' ',lname) 
        from lang_course_instructors 
        where slno=a.class_inst_id) as instname 
FROM `lang_course_details_session` as a, 
              `lang_course_details` as b,
              `lang_course_outline` as c,  
              `lang_course_category` as d 
where a.`class_status` != '' and 
      a.course_id=b.course_id and 
      c.outline_id=b.outline_id and 
      c.catid=d.slno;
```

If I am running this query without create view statement then it is returning proper records from the database. But when I am trying to run the same from the VIEW then it is showing Subquery returns more than one row.

This issue is in the sub-query:

```
( select comp_name 
  from lang_company_details 
  where comp_id = (
    select comp_id 
    from lang_company_details_courses 
    where course_id=a.course_id
  )
) as company
```

If I am removing this query then everything is working well but with this query, the view is not working.

Comment: Can you show us the table structure and give us an idea of the data that's in there?

Comment: Try adding `LIMIT 1` to the subquery.

Comment: Why are you using subqueries in your `SELECT`?  You can `JOIN` them instead....